# Why does PartialEq return a bool, when PartialOrd is more nuanced and returns Option<Ordering>?

Tags: rust, equality

It seems asymmetric and basic, so I want to understand the reasoning of this, why is that `PartialOrd` defines `partial_cmp`, to return `Option<Ordering>`;

```rust
fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Rhs) -> Option<Ordering> {}
```

And `PartialEq` defines `eq` to return `bool`

```rust
fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool {}
```

Why doesn't `PartialEq::eq` return `Option<Eq>` where `None` represents things that can't be determined to be equal? Why does `PartialEq` get to skirt having the knowledge of which values can not compared for equality and thus which prevent the implementation of a full `Eq` trait, and yet `PartialOrd` has to know which values can not be compared for a full ordering (so it can return that information to the user as `None`)?

Comment: At one time (pre Rust 1.0) `partial_cmp` returned `Ordering` not an option.

Comment: I couldn't find a discussion on the topic, but it's likely because `eq` returning `bool` is consistent: two things are either equal or they are not - even if they are both given the same label like `NAN`. With ordering, it's not as pleasant because you get  contraditions like `a <= b == false` but also `a >= b == false`. This isn't the case with `==`; if `(a == b) == false` then `(a != b) == true`.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of a few reason's why these traits are defined the way they are:

1. `PartialEq` is the trait for the `==` operator. If it were to return an `Option`, language ergonomics around `if`s and other control flows would need to at least be reconsidered.
2. When considering whether values are equal or not, "non-comparable" values fall into the latter category. There need not be a third answer; either they're equal or they're not. This is the same for `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=` provided by `PartialOrd`, they all return `bool` regardless if the values are "non-comparable" (they return `false` in that case).
3. The meaning of "Partial" in the types differ. "Partial" in `PartialOrd` means that types may not have a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Whereas "Partial" in `PartialEq` means types may not have complete [equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (may not be reflexive, symmetric, or transitive). The naming is similar because they both cover cases where types don't behave nicely, but they are conveying slightly different concepts. The APIs do not need to be identical.

Answer (score 5):

Because `PartialOrd` is cheating a bit, by mathematical standards.

Abstractly speaking, a mathematical structure is defined by two things: some operations and some axioms associated to those operations. In a programming language, we can define traits (or typeclasses, or whatever your favorite language calls them) which embody mathematical structures. We define the trait to support certain operations and simply trust that the programmer follows the axioms.

[Total orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_ordered_set) (i.e. `Ord`) and [partial orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (i.e. `PartialOrd`) are usually modeled using a single operation: `<=`. And the difference in the two structures is based on what properties we require of `<=`. Likewise, [partial equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_equivalence_relation) (`PartialEq`) and [equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (`Eq`) are defined in terms of `==`, and the two differ only in what properties.

If we were to define `PartialOrd` and `Ord` in this way in Rust, it would look something like (I'm omitting the `RHS` type argument for simplicity reasons)

```
trait PartialOrd : PartialEq {
  fn less_or_equal(self, other: Self) -> bool;
}
trait Ord : PartialOrd {}
```

which looks more like what the `PartialEq` / `Eq` dichotomy looks like. Rust chose to implement `PartialOrd` in terms of another operator: the trichotomy operator `partial_cmp` and `cmp`. In any *total ordering*, we can define an operator `cmp(a, b)` which returns whether `a` is smaller than, equal to, or larger than `b`. And in a total ordering, exactly one of those is true. In a *partial ordering*, however, we can still *define* this operator `partial_cmp(a, b)`, but there's a fourth option, namely that the two are simply not comparable.

As for why Rust did it this way, I couldn't say for certain. Haskell has a similar setup, with an `Ord` typeclass, and in Haskell you can implement *either* `<=` or `compare`, and you get the other one for free. Python used to use `__cmp__` (which is basically Rust's `cmp`) but Python 3 switched completely to defining `<=` and using [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) for comparisons.

We could debate back and forth which mechanism is better. `cmp` has its benefits in terms of clarity and symmetry, but `<=` is better for studying abstract mathematics. If you define both structures the mathematical way (`==` for `PartialEq` and `<=` for `PartialOrd`), then in both cases you get a single binary operator which "returns" `bool`, and all of the other differences are in the axioms. The reason we don't have that satisfying symmetry in Rust is that Rust's `PartialOrd` is defined in terms of an operator that only makes total mathematical sense in `Ord`; we've taken a total ordering operator and removed some of its legs, leaving an operator that only works "some of the time".